# Getting the custom control of a cell

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `Datagrid` with some columns.
In one of those columns (Let's say column 3 ) I have a `TextBlock` in normal mode and a custom control version of a `Textbox` in it when we are in cell editing mode.
Now there is another column (Lets say column 5) that when I am entering values in that column, depending on some conditions it can affect the value we have in that column 3.
So my question is how can I grab the control in that column 3 to be able to modify its value, set it to readonly, etc..

Comment: What do you mean by "grab the control"? Are you trying to do this in code behind for some reason?

Comment: @EdPlunkett : My WPF is mostly in code behind, no MVVM, so if it was not in a grid I was thinking of giving it an x:Name and accessing its properties like text, readonly...but it is in grid so can't give name, so have to somehow get to the control in that grid.

Comment: Do you want to grab the TextBlock or the TextBox and exactly when you want to grab it?

Comment: Have tried Findcontrol method? TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb = (TextBlock)DataGridID.FindControl("TextBlockID");
    tb.Properties = //etc.

Comment: @mm8 I asked it in a more clear way in here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493718/getting-control-inside-a-datagrid-cell