# Getting control inside a datagrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have something like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Occurences" Width="Auto">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Occurences, Converter={StaticResource ListConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,5,10,5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <myCustomControls:OccurencesManualEntry/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

For the current row, When I am in ANOTHER column of this grid, Is it possible to get the **`<myCustomControls:OccurencesManualEntry/>`** so I can set some of its properties?

Comment: No, it's not since the OccurencesManualEntry control only exists then the Occurences cell is in edit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the `<myCustomControls:OccurencesManualEntry/>` so I can set some of its properties?

No, it's not since the `OccurencesManualEntry` control only exists when the "Occurences" cell is in edit mode.

What you could is to add a dependency property to the `OccurencesManualEntry` control and bind this one to a source property of your data object:

```
<myCustomControls:OccurencesManualEntry SomeProperty="{Binding SourceProperty}"/>
```

You could then set this source property from another cell:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

---

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = sender as TextBox;
    var yourDataObject = txtBox.DataContext as YourDataClass;
    yourDataObject.SourceProperty = "value...";
}
```

Make sure that the data class implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and raises the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the source property.

Comment: That would be the standard MVVM approach.